# How to benchmark browser performance against a given feature

Tags: browsers

A new drawing feature is about to be delivered to our customer, but an issue was discovered:

- This drawing feature is particularly slow when running on Firefox.

I am wondering if it is possible to benchmark this feature against each browser?

Anyone knows any tools / technique?

- This new drawing feature basically allows a user to draw custom shapes on a web page. When running on Firefox, there is a noticeable lagging and the shapes are more jerky / choppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the browser embedded developer console, to open it on firefox for example, press the on keyboard: Ctrl+Shift+J or Cmd+Shift+J on a Mac, then click on tab performance, start recording, test your feature, verify your benchmark data.

[Firefox browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: ? Can you please be more specific? Your answer is too vague.

Comment: I will accept it as the answer since you pointed me to the right direction. The actual technique I am using will be: measure the frame rate of Firefox while allowing a script to draw a certain shape.